# Программное включение и выключение GPS

Tags: android

Есть вопрос по поводу программного включения и выключения GPS-а то есть, включить его без ведома пользователя и выключить, т.к по сотовым сетям координаты вылавливать слишком уж неудовлетворительно, погрешность большая. Вопрос состоит именно в том как включить и выключить.

Comment: попросить пользователя включить. Самый правильный способ.

Answer (score 1):

Полноценно включить/выключить GPS невозможно, максимум, что вы можете сделать - это напрaвить юзера в настройки GPS с помощью Intent.

На *некоторых* девайсах есть эксплойт, который всё-таки позволяет программно включить GPS. [Смотрим сюды.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker/5305835#5305835) Если всё-таки будете пользоваться этим кодом, то я бы порекомендовал вам занести код в блоки try-catch.